# multiple inheritance exhaustive check in kotlin is not working as expected for interfaces without a forced cast and supressing the warning

Tags: kotlin

I have the following a case of multiple inheritance and the purpose is to obtain exhaustive checking for both all levels.

```
sealed class Command {
    data class Start(override val attr1: Double) : Command(), Trait1
    data class Start2(override val attr1: Double, val another: Boolean) : Command(), Trait1
    object Stop : Command()

    interface Trait1 {
        val attr1: Double
    }
}
```

```
if (command is Command.Trait1) {
    ...
            when (command) {
                is Command.Start2-> ...
                is Command.Start -> ...
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Undefined case")
            }
    ...
}
```

I need both levels of inheritance.

I would like to also have exhaustive checking for `Trait1`. With it the `else` branch will disappear and if a new class uses it then the compiler will help me add a new branch.

Currently it looks like this is not possible.

If I try to add a branch that doesn't implement `Trait1` then the compiler wouldn't see it as a problem.

```
when (command) {
    is Command.Start2-> ...
    is Command.Start -> ...
    is Comment.Stop -> ...   // this will compile, I was expecting it to fail
    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Undefined case")
}
```

It looks like the type of command is `Command` instead of `Command.Trait1` even though there is an instance check before it.

The only solution I have found so far is to cast and suppress the warning. This will fix the problem of adding implementations that are not of type `Trait1`. But there we still have the `else` branch, if we remove it then we get a compilation error.

```
@Suppress("USELESS_CAST")
when (command as Command.Trait1) {
    is Command.Start2-> ...
    is Command.Start -> ...
    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Undefined case") // this should not be required anymore
}
```

Any other options?

Comment: Kotlin 1.5 will have sealed interfaces. Not sure if that will satisfy what you’re trying to do though.

Comment: That will solve the problem... But until then...

Comment: In Kotlin 1.4.30 sealed interfaces are shipped as a preview feature. You may try it with [respectful compiler option](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#try-sealed-interfaces-and-package-wide-hierarchies-of-sealed-classes)